# Question involving PDE's

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function of a single variable and $F(x,y)$ is defined by $F(x,y) = f(x^2-y)$.

a) show that F satisifies the PDE $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + 2x \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 0$

b) Given that $F(0,y) = \sin(y)$ for all y, find a formula for $F(x,y)$

I am able to do part A, but unsure as to how to obtain part b. All help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to write it like this: $F(x,y) = F(0, y-x^2)$.

**Edit**

Indeed, we have $F(a,b) = f(a^2-b)$, hence

$$F(0, y-x^2) = f(0^2-(y-x^2)) = f(x^2-y) = F(x,y).$$

Comment: how did you get there?

Comment: @Reese See edit.